# AngularJS - routeProvider genera url invalida

Tags: html, angularjs, menú

Cuando intento llamar mi archivo "opcion1" desde mi carpeta de templates en la url solo aparece

> http://localhost:7881/doc/#!/#%2Fopcion1

y no me permite acensar a mi ruta mas sin encambio si modifico la URL a

> http://localhost:7881/doc/#!/opcion1

me hace el llamado de manera correcta
mi barra de navegación la defino de la siguiente manera:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#/opcion1">Opción 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#/opcion2">Opción 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#/opcion3">Opción 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#/opcion4">Opción 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#/">Inicio</a></li>
</ul>
```

y hago la llamada desde AngularJS con:

```
var mainAplication = angular.module('herbApp', ['ngRoute']);
mainAplication.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'resources/temps/inicio.php',
    controller: 'inicio'
})
.when('/opcion1', {
    templateUrl: 'resources/temps/opcion1.php',
    controller: 'inicio'
})

}])
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, lo agradecería demasiado.

Comment: El que te muestre `#%2` por el encoding. #%2 es el `/`. Investigando lei que angular cambio su version del encoding y por lo tanto te muestra eso. Para que no te ocurra intenta con esto a ver que pasa y escribe si funciono: `app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);`

Comment: Muchas gracias solucioné el error con la respuesta de Einer que se muestra debajo, muchas gracias, me he dado cuenta que debo investigar mas, excelente codificación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que agregar el simbolo `#!` a la url. Segun el commit [aa077e8](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52), ahora se agrega el simbolo  `!` a la url.

Asi que cambia:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#/opcion1">Opción 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/opcion2">Opción 2</a></li>
 //...
</ul>
```

Por:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#!/opcion1">Opción 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#!/opcion2">Opción 2</a></li>
 //...
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pude solucionarlo gracias a ti, en verdad me estuve rompiendo la cabeza por demasiado tiempo, espero tengas una bonita codificación